# Drools is passing utf-8 characters in malformed format

Tags: java, eclipse, character-encoding, mule, drools

i am using mule esb with drools and jbpm to create an ESB project.
I am also using Anypoint studio (which is eclipse in heart)

this is my .drl file (which is utf-8) :

```
package com.hamgam.hit.esb 

import com.hamgam.hit.esb.*; 
import org.mule.MessageExchangePattern 

global org.mule.module.bpm.MessageService mule; 

dialect "mvel" 

declare 
    XMLDTO 
    @role( event ) 
end

rule "Rule One For Mule And Drools" 
lock-on-active

when 
    $x:XMLDTO(eval(this.containsKeyValue("firstname" , "حامد")) || eval(this.containsKeyValue("lastname" , "رضایی"))) 
then 
    modify ($x) { setEmcEyes(true)} 
end
```

and this is the containsKeyValue(String b,String a) method inside my XMLDTO class :

```
/**
 * <firstname>Moien</firstname>
 *
 * @param key attribute name e.g firstname
 * @param value attributes value e.g Moien
 * @return if there is a key with given value in elements map
 */
public boolean containsKeyValue(String key,String value){
    if(elements.containsKey(key) && elements.get(key).contains(value))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Note : elements is a map that contains utf-8 strings.
the problem is String key and String value that are being passed to this method from drools are not in correct format. e.g value is "Ø­Ø§Ù…Ø¯" where it actually should be "حامد".

Note : mule is working fine with UTF-8 and i am pretty sure that devil lies in drools.

any way to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "utf-8 strings"? If the map is a `Map<String,String>`, there is no UTF-8 encoding involved; Java strings are UTF-16, but you don't really have to worry about this. Is the rule written exactly as shown?

Comment: i mean the input value is a utf-8 text.(e.g the value for 'firstname' in .drl file)  . and yes the rule is exactly as shown

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue using 6.1.0. You'll have to demonstrate how you insert an object containing these strings when it does not work. Also, I suggest you try with a simple object containing just one String field.

Comment: BTW, the string you have claimed as maimed by Drools ("Ø­Ø§Ù…Ø¯") are  bytes decoded as ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1) characters. I don't know how you got these characters, but it could be that you have some weak points in your system's encoding configuration.